# grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1

Tags: grpc, qnx

I have cross compiled gRPC (v1.27.3) for QNX 7 (ARM) platform. I am using the protobuf which was already available for our system (QNX ARM v3.11.4).

I used following cmake command to build gRPC for compilation process

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING=1 -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package -DgRPC_ZLIB_PROVIDER=package -DOPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY=$QNX_TARGET/aarch64le/usr/lib/libcrypto.a -DOPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY=$TARGET/aarch64le/usr/lib/libssl.a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/tmp/qnxarm/toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/qnxarm/inst ../..

make plugins

make -j4 

sudo make install
```

After compiling, I am able to see the binaries in `/tmp/qnxarm/inst`  folder.

I copied those binaries in our code to compile the application for QNX.

While compiling I am getting this issue:

```
<local_directory>/grpc/aarch64/qnx/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
lib/qmonitor/proto/CMakeFiles/QMonitorProto.dir/build.make:105: recipe for target 'lib/qmonitor/proto/QAicMonitorInternal.grpc.pb.cc' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/qmonitor/proto/QAicMonitorInternal.grpc.pb.cc] Error 1
```

Please help me to know what is wrong? or what should be done to solve this.

Do we need to add the PATH in gRPCTargets.cmake file which is generated in lib folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've compiled the gRPC tools for your QNX ARM system -- so the version of grpc_cpp_plugin you made is expecting to be run on your QNX system, not your build host.

The usual approach for this sort of thing is to make a second copy of gRPC compiled for your build host, and then instruct your application build to link the libraries from the cross build, but call the grpc_cpp_plugin compiled for the build host.

Comment: Thanks Will Miles, for your response.

Comment: I am using grpc binaries from the installed folder, to compile my QNX application (which is arm compatible). 

Can you explain the second paragraph, which you answered. (the instruct part)

Also why we need second copy of host grpc_cpp_plugin? since that binary will be for x86 machine, but here we are compiling QNX for arm.

Comment: grpc_cpp_plugin is part of the toolchain, like the compiler and linker.  It's used to create some C++ files to compile, so it needs to run on the x86 build host.  It's only used during the build process; it doesn't need to be installed on your QNX target.

Comment: How I can mention this toolchain path while building QNX application?
I have already included the grpc_cpp_plugin in PATH variable.

Comment: I have successfully compiled and generated the binaries. Now to use this binaries I need to mention the path of grpc_cpp_plugin. So do I need to use the gRPCTargets.cmake to give the path or any other method?